# Is it true that $((A\rightarrow B)\land(¬A\rightarrow ¬B))↔((¬A) \;\;\text{⊕}\;\; B)$?

Tags: logic, algorithms, propositional-calculus

Is $((A\rightarrow B)\land(¬A\rightarrow ¬B))↔((¬A) \;\;\text{⊕}\;\; B)$ true? I found it's true but I don't know what to use it for besides refactoring. How interesting is the statement A→B if not also ¬A→¬B? For example `radiation → energy` and not `¬radiation→¬energy` is not very interesting is it? The interesting statement would be `radiation → energy ^ ¬radiation→¬energy` or `goal → score ^ ¬goal→¬score` so that there is determinism and no other way (you can't score if you don't make a goal). It's not legal if you can score without actually making a goal.

A→B is not very interesting when B all the time can happen regardless of the truth value of A in any case.

"Either A or B" is that B can't happen if not A has not happened and that excludes $ A\rightarrow B.$

I have a simple model where I think the bottom is more like YES ⊕ NO (and it doesn't at all look like YES OR NO even though the picture doesn't say that YES and NO can't both be true for the same input(?)

[image]

Comment: What is this???

Comment: Are you missing some parentheses? Does caret mean "and"? What does "AXB" means?

Comment: AXB means A XOR B

Comment: @rotten The rewrite is `((A→B)^(¬A→~B))↔(¬A) XOR B` ("you can't score unless you make a goal").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you propose is an equivalence: see (1) and (2) to follow...

(1) Note that $$(A \rightarrow B)\land (\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot B)$$

$$\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \land (B \rightarrow A)\tag{contrapositive}$$
$$\equiv A \leftrightarrow B) $$
$$\not\equiv (A\rightarrow B)$$

That is, what you are proposing is a biconditional: $A\;$ *if and only if* $\;B$.

In a strict implication $\;A \rightarrow B,\;$ $A$ is a *sufficient condition* for $B$, whereas $\,B$ is a *necessary condition* for $\,A\,$.

When you want to state a relationship in which condition $A$ is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\,B\,$, then you write $\,A \iff B$ or $A\,\leftrightarrow B$.

But there are many relationships in which one variable implies the other, but not the other way around. If $A \subseteq B$, then we know that $a\in A \rightarrow b\in B$, but we cannot say that it is also the case that $b\in B \rightarrow b \in A$.

(2) Note also that $$\lnot A\; \text{ XOR}\;\; B \equiv (\lnot A \lor B)\land \lnot(\lnot A \land B)\quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{1: unpack XOR}$$
$$\equiv (A \rightarrow B) \land (A \lor \lnot B)\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{2: $\lnot p \lor q \equiv p \rightarrow q$; 3: DeMorgan's }$$
$$\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \land (\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot B)\quad\quad\quad\tag{4: same reason as 2}$$
$$\equiv (A\rightarrow B) \land (B\rightarrow A) \tag{as shown above}$$
$$\equiv A \leftrightarrow B\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{see top}$$

So both the left side and the right side of your equivalence (which is an equivalence) are equivalent, as well, to $A\leftrightarrow B$

Comment: Thank you. I set A=goal. ¬A→¬B means "You can't score without making a goal" and A→B maens that a goal implicates a score. If we didn't have ¬A→¬B then somebody could score with no goal. Now I'm not sure about the second roof of the notation above i.e. `(A→B∧(B→A` looks somewhat incomplete and not wellmatched parantheses.

Comment: $(\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot B)$ is the contrapositive of (and equivalent to): $(B \rightarrow A)$

Comment: Yes it's true that a score implies a goal and vice versa. But now we don't say which is which. A score (B) can't happen before a goal (A). How did we lose that?

Comment: In English, (as opposed to logic), there is ambiguity. We use "or" a lot to mean the exclusive or (XOR), even though in logic, "or" by itself is weaker.  That's the case, too, with conditionals.

Comment: Nick, why the "unaccept"? You can still accept even if a question has been closed...why it was closed, I don't know! seems like a perfectly good question to me!

Comment: If you conclude "Yes" or "No" to the question I will accept. I think the answer is yes and that we should conclude whether the statement is true or false simply. Thank you very much I just wanted to logically find out about XOR which I don't intepret like OR. E.b. "Is `((A→B)∧(¬A→¬B))↔((¬A)⊕B)` true? " Answer: Yes or why not.

Comment: Done, top, and bottom, of post...;-)

Answer (score 1):

As amWhy showed in his answer left hand side is a biconditional. Let P denote the negation of A. Then, on the right hand side you have P XOR B which is true if and only if P and B have mutually exclusive values. Since P is the negation of A, P and A has mutually exclusive values. Therefore, A and B has the same value in other words A iff B. So, both sides are equal.

Comment: Thanks. So logically we can't say the difference between a goal and a score in football.

Comment: Well, I guess, that depends on your definition of a goal or even a score. As an extreme example, I might assume that own goal is not a goal. However, it is a score. In the usual, "legal" sense (that is determined by a referee), there is no difference.